# Removing extra commas from string after using String.Join to convert array to string (C#)

Tags: c#, string, join

I'm converting an array into a string using `String.Join`. A small issue I have is that, in the array some index positions will be blank. An example is below:

```
array[1] = "Firstcolumn"
array[3] = "Thirdcolumn"
```

By using String.Join(",", array);, I'll get the following:

> Firstcolumn,,Thirdcolumn

Note the extra `,.`

How can I remove the extra commas from the string, or ideally not include blank indices when using String.Join?

Comment: After join use string.Replace(",,", ",");

Comment: @sh_kamalh That wouldn't handle the case of "1,,,2".

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this :):

```
var res = string.Join(",", array.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

This will join only the strings which is not `null` or `""`.

Comment: I like the fact you are tackling the cause of the problem and not just bandaging the problem with a hack!

Answer (score 34):

A simple solution would be to use linq, by filtering out the empty items before joining.

```
// .net 3.5
string.Join(",", array.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)).ToArray());
```

In .NET 4.0 you could also make use of [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if you also want to filter out the items that are blank or consist of white space characters only (note that in .NET 4.0 you don't have to call `ToArray` in this case):

```
// .net 4.0
string.Join(",", array.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)));
```

Comment: +1 for at the time of writing being the only answer to mention ToArray (which by the way is unnecessary in .NET 4).

Answer (score 3):

You could use linq to remove the empty fields.

```
var joinedString = String.Join(",", array.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c));
```

Comment: He asked specifically how, not just in theory, try supply code?

Answer (score 1):

Extension method:

```
public static string ToStringWithoutExtraCommas(this object[] array)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object o in array)
    {

        if ((o is string && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)o)) || o != null)
            sb.Append(o.ToString()).Append(",");
    }

    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This will not insert any commas at all. But he *wants* commas, just not after empty entries.

Comment: -1 a string can be empty without being null in which case the additional commas are included anyway.

Comment: still doesn't work. it will never get to the `o is string && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)o)` part when string is not null.

Comment: Right I realized that And fixed it before you posted the comment, it works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression solution:

```
yourString = new Regex(@"[,]{2,}").Replace(yourString, @",");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Join(",", array.Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Join(",", Array.FindAll(array, a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)));
```

How about this one? Cons and pros comparing to LINQ solution? At least it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Simple extension method

```
namespace System
{
    public static class Extenders
    {
        public static string Join(this string separator, bool removeNullsAndWhiteSpaces, params string[] args)
        {
            return removeNullsAndWhiteSpaces ? string.Join(separator, args?.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))) : string.Join(separator, args);
        }
        public static string Join(this string separator, bool removeNullsAndWhiteSpaces, IEnumerable<string> args)
        {
            return removeNullsAndWhiteSpaces ? string.Join(separator, args?.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))) : string.Join(separator, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var str = ".".Join(true, "a", "b", "", "c");
//or 
var arr = new[] { "a", "b", "", "c" };
str = ".".Join(true, arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string.Join(",", string.Join(",", array).Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

v('_')V